# jQuery .val() Issue

Tags: jquery, ajax

Somewhat new to JS/jQuery, but I am trying to change the value of a hidden field to the sum of a JSON object's specific value as it is looped. Here is what I have:

```
            <form>
            <input id="totDistance" type="hidden" value="" />
        </form>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "loadPolys.php",
   dataType: "json",
   success: function(returnedJson){

    jQuery.each(returnedJson, function(i, val) {

    var curType = val.type;
    var curAlias = val.alias;
    var curDistance = val.distance;
    totDistance += parseInt(curDistance, 10);
    $('#totDistance').val(totDistance);
    });

},
   error: function(){
    alert("oh no");
   }

});
});
</script>
```

Though the input field keeps being set to "[object HTMLInputElement]1734". The values to be added are 17 and 34, so the data is being pulled... and totDistance is set to 51... What am I doing wrong? *noobie*

Comment: Where is `totDistance` defined?

Comment: This solved the issue. In the beginning I defined totDistance outside of all functions, but defining it inside of the ajax callback function worked wonders.

Comment: @KevinB I think it is IE specific issue.. where `totDistance` is equivalent to `docuement.getElementById('totDistance')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try defining the `totDistance` variable:

```
...
success: function(returnedJson){

var totDistance = 0;

jQuery.each(returnedJson, function(i, val) {
...
```

Comment: Ah. This did the trick! I'm still trying to learn everything I can about the JS/jQuery world, so I appreciate the helping hand. :)

Comment: @josephndenton Yes, totDistance will be the element in IE at least, until you redefine it.

Comment: @josephndenton Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are facing is an IE specific issue where it `totDistance` is getting evaluated as `document.getElementById('totDistance')` That is when it has an matching element with ID (totDistance). To avoid this.. simply declare the var and initialize to 0.

Also It is better to set the hidden element outside the `.each`

```
success: function(returnedJson){    
    var totDistance = 0;  //declared a var
    jQuery.each(returnedJson, function(i, val) {
      var curType = val.type;
      var curAlias = val.alias;
      var curDistance = val.distance;
      totDistance += parseInt(curDistance, 10);      
    });

    $('#totDistance').val(totDistance); //Moved outside of .each    
}
```